# How to enter opportunities in NPSP's opportunity tab?

Tags: opportunity, contact, npsp

I am using the Non-Profit-Starter-Pack (NPSP) with the 1-to-1 model.

I want to create an opportunity from the opportunity tab. I tried to insert a field for `contact` here, but cannot find it when customizing the view.

When I assign the opportunity to the 1-to-1 account, it does not show up in the contact.

However, when I enter the opportunity from the contact view, it does get assigned automatically and rightly.

*How can I enter a contact's opportunity from the opportunity tab in NPSP's 1-to-1 model?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely associated with the fact that you don't have a setting turned on to create contact roles automatically in the 1-to-1 model. Go to All Tabs and Contacts and Organizations Settings. Edit the setting and make sure the Enable Opportunity Contact Role Trigger checkbox is checked and choose the appropriate Default Role from the picklist.

Hope that solves it for you. It could be a couple of other things if that doesn't work, but that's my first bet.